# Vue mapState non reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I try to get the state from the store using the mapState function, But I can't use the generated code that returns the values into my template code ...

```
<template>
         // Some code
                <template v-if="!isLoggedIn">
                    // Some code
                </template>
                <template v-else>
                    // Some code
                    {{ currentUser.name }} 
                </template>
    
        // Some code
</template>

<script>
    import { mapState } from "vuex";

    export default {
        // Some code
        computed: {
          ...mapState({auth : ['currentUser', 'isLoggedIn','customers']})
        }
    }
</script>
```

instead the following code work

```
<script>
    import { mapState } from "vuex";

    export default {
        // Some code
        computed: {
          currentUser() {
                return this.$store.state.auth.currentUser
            },
            isLoggedIn() {
                return this.$store.state.auth.isLoggedIn
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

Warning message

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "isLoggedIn" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

Thanks in advance

Comment: We need to see the basic structure of your Vuex store and modules. Pleeease and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The right syntax to access non-root properties is the following (using arrow functions) :

```
computed: {
...mapState({
  currentUser: state => state.auth.currentUser,
  isLoggedIn: state => state.auth.isLoggedIn,
  customers: state => state.auth.customers
})}
```

Check the [documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper).

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to access values from a namespaced vuex module called `auth`, pass the name of the module as the first argument and the array of values to map as the second argument:

```
computed: {
    ...mapState('auth', ['currentUser', 'isLoggedIn','customers'])
}
```

Comment: Afaik it wont work, this syntax work for mapActions, but not for mapState

Comment: @Aldarund The syntax does work for `mapState`. However the determining factor is whether or not the module is namespaced. It won't work for a non-namespaced module.

Comment: @aaronofleonard hm, right, just checked and it works. But i dont see such example in docs -> https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#binding-helpers-with-namespace

Comment: @Aldarund Yeah, the docs don't seem to have it. I was trying to find a link about this to put in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can mapState the module and then use, say `this.auth.isLoggedin`